# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'. im getting this error while writing a csv file in a array . how do i solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import wget  
with open('__memes_magic_thumbnails.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
print(data)
k=0
for link in data:
     print(k)
     
     wget.download(link , "vid/logo.jpg")
     k+=1

print("succes")
```

for this code im getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "i:\Meme Channel\channel1\automated_youtube_channel-master\automated_youtube_channel-master\scraper.py", line 12, in <module>
    wget.download(link , "vid/logo.jpg")
  File "C:\Users\Sambhaji Karbhari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 505, in download
    prefix = detect_filename(url, out)
  File "C:\Users\Sambhaji Karbhari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 484, in detect_filename
    names["url"] = filename_from_url(url) or ''
  File "C:\Users\Sambhaji Karbhari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 230, in filename_from_url
    fname = os.path.basename(urlparse.urlparse(url).path)
  File "C:\Users\Sambhaji Karbhari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 392, in urlparse    
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
  File "C:\Users\Sambhaji Karbhari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 128, in _coerce_args    return _decode_args(args) + (_encode_result,)
  File "C:\Users\Sambhaji Karbhari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 112, in _decode_args    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
  File "C:\Users\Sambhaji Karbhari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 112, in <genexpr>   
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

here i downloading a image from the link which is taken fro array which is inserted in it from a csv file.

Comment: Looks like `data` is a list of lists...

Comment: What does `print(link)` print?